# usage of "in spite of" for weather

Tags: phrase-usage

I found the usage "In spite of subject v-ing".
The question I ask myself is
"Can I use this structure for weather?"
E.g

> 1. In spite of it being hot, we went out.
> 2. In spite of it being rainy, we went out.
> 3. In spite of it being cold, we went out.

If I write

> "In spite of being felt unwell, I go to school."

Can "being felt unwell" be passive structrure or not?

Answer (score 5):

Your weather usages are quite acceptable. However, “being felt unwell” is not an acceptable usage; one would say (or write) “In spite of feeling unwell...”.

Answer (score 1):

Your weather sentences are all correct (even if "despite it being hot" or "although it was hot" might sound a bit more elegant).

"In spite of" can be followed by a passive - e.g. "in spite of having been disappointed, she was still determined to succeed" or "in spite of being shot, he's still alive".

"In spite of feeling unwell" is correct.

"Being felt unwell" would make no sense.  You could write "being judged unwell", "being thought unwell", "being found unwell" or "being deemed unwell".  For example (if your mother thought you were unwell but you went to school anyway: "in spite of being thought unwell, I went to school".  But it would probably be more usual to use the active: "in spite of my mother thinking I was unwell, I went to school".